# GitLab CI: git pull instead git clone

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I have git directory on server. 
Every push in Master branch i want to do git pull in this directory.
I try to do that with gitlab-ci-multi-runner.
I made *shell* runner, but by default he do repository clone, and then call my commands.

How to change git clone on git pull?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Project Settings page, under "Builds", change `git clone` to `git fetch`.

[image: Project Settings]

Note, `git pull` does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. So you don't want CI to `git pull`. GitLab CI performs a `git fetch` followed by a `git checkout <commit>`.

Comment: Anyway he made path like <working-directory>/builds/<short-token>/<concurrent-id>/<namespace>/<project-name>

Comment: @НиколаевСергей What is your point? That's what is supposed to happen.